# C# pinvoke free native c++ memory

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, pinvoke

If i have a c++ function which returns a char* like this:

```
char *cctalk_app_event_name(DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE);
```

And the corresponding C# signature:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("cctalk.dll", EntryPoint = "cctalk_app_event_name", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern System.IntPtr cctalk_app_event_name(DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE param0);
```

If the native code returns a char* allocated with the new keyword, i am for sure gonna have a memleak each time i call this function C#? Is there a way i can free that memory?

Comment: How does it work when using the DLL from C/C++?

Comment: Yes, you will need to free it. You can either make a `Free` function in your C++ library that frees it with whatever allocated it (then call it from your C# code), or you might be able to use [Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem(v=vs.110).aspx) if it was allocated with the COM task memory allocator.

Comment: I only have the .h of the dll and no doc at all about how was it implemented, so how do i know if it was allocated with the COM task mem allocator? Probably not since it is a plain old c++ lib..

Comment: It seems that there is documentation. You should obtain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch from looking at the function name is that this may well be returning a pointer to a string constant within the DLL, in which case you don't need to worry about freeing the pointer anyway.

If the manual for the SDK ([link here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/106567829/200-338-0-2-Money-Controls-CcTalk-User-Manual)) wasn't any use, then I'd disassemble the DLL and look at what that function did, but don't worry about how to delete it before you've established that you need to.

Comment: I looked at the manual, the signature is actually `const char *cctalk_app_event_name (PDG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE code);` and the sample code doesn't free the returned string. It's on page 45.

Comment: I'd guess it's just indexing into an array of string constants.  It might be quite easy to write a little app which called it several hundred million times and see if it leaks.  If you did that in C++ then you wouldn't have 10s of MB of .NET bloat and GC noise on top of the app memory.

Comment: You were right, it is actually const! It was still good to know what would happen if it wasnt heh

Comment: @user1777914 it being a const char* doesn't mean it wasn't dynamically allocated, if just means you can't modify it via that pointer.  But I expect you'll be OK anyway.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because it's much quicker to type out a question on Stack Overflow than to Google it, right? Right?

Comment: To be fair to the OP, I couldn't find the docs in a form I didn't have to sign up to (and pay for) a commercial service to be able to read, and it's not a foregone conclusion that the docs actually answer this question explicitly anyway.

Comment: @user My point is that whilst you have answers to the question you asked, you don't have a solution to the problem here. That is to be found in the docs. That's what you should be doing, rather than relying on our hunches.

Comment: @WillDean I was able to download the PDF without registering or paying for anything. http://bugmenot.com/view/scribd.com I think OP is just bad at using the internet (Google + other well known sites).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any documentation or source then you cannot know whether or not the memory was allocated with new. If it was allocated with new then it needs to be deallocated with delete. That can only be done from the native code. If that is needed then the DLL will need to export a deallocator for you.

Other possibilities include allocation from a shared heap, e.g. the COM heap. Not very likely. Or perhaps the string is statically allocated and does not need deallocation. This final option is usually the case when a functions returns a C string as a return value. If you had to guess, that's the percentage option. In any case, if there's no way for you to deallocate the string, what else can you do?

The only way you can be sure is to have documentation, or source code, or support from the author. I appreciate that you want to know the solution, but your only hope are the options listed in the first sentence of this paragraph.

I find it hard to believe that a library this complex has no documentation. How did you come by this library? Are you really sure there are no docs?

Comment: As you and I are playing pedantry tonight, I'll argue with the last paragraph - disassembly is a possibility, and I could help him with that, so that's two strikes....  :-)

Comment: @WillDean I suppose reversing is possible. Docs would be more sane.